# Free fall simulation: problems defining varying air resistance

Tags: physics, numerical-methods, differential-equations

So this is the situation: I'm doing a coding project which will model Felix Baumgartner's free fall from a height of around 40 km. As part of this project, I'm supposed to demonstrate the use of the Leapfrog method to solve the differential equations involved and compare this with analytical solutions. Baumgartner reached a terminal velocity of 373 m/s, and I do get this result with the analytical solutions, but not by use of the Leapfrog method. My python code is below, and I'm almost certain my problem is in assigning the **k** values, the drag force constant.

```
m = 73+23
g = 9.81
A = 1.73 * 0.396
roe = 1.2
Cd = 1

def k(height):
    k = (Cd * A * 1.2 * mt.exp((-height)/(1000*7.64)))/2
    return k

y_c_input = input('Choose a jump height in metres: ')
y_c = float(y_c_input)
ti = 0
tf = int(input('How long would you like to fall for (in seconds)?'))
n = tf * 10
t = np.linspace(ti, tf, n)
y = np.zeros(n)
ymid = np.zeros(n)
v = np.zeros(n)
vmid = np.zeros(n)

y[0] = y_c
ymid[0] = y_c
v[0] = 0
vmid[0] = 0

dt = (tf - ti)/(n-1)
terminal = np.linspace(-373, -373,n)
for i in range(n):
    ymid[i] = y[i-1] + (dt/2)*v[i-1]
    y[i] = y[i-1] + dt * vmid[i]
    vmid[i] = v[i-1] + (dt/2) * (-g - (k(y[i])/m) * v[i-1] * abs(v[i-1]))
    v[i] = v[i-1] + (dt) * (-g - (k(ymid[i])/m) * vmid[i] * abs(vmid[i]))

plt.plot(t, vc)
plt.show()
```

I'm meant to plot graphs of vertical height, and vertical velocity against time. The function **k** above is the drag force constant as a function of height (so not a constant as he fell from a height where air density was much lower). At the moment, the plot shows a terminal velocity of around 50 m/s. All quantities are in SI units.

My specific question is: where have I gone wrong in calling my **k** values?

Comment: What's `vc` and what time are you using?

Comment: Why are you running two variants of Verlet integration in parallel? The iteration of `y` and `vmid` is enough to run Leapfrog Verlet. Reconstruct `v[i]=(vmid[i-1]+vmid[i])/2`.

Comment: Hey guys. I figured it out. The code above is slightly different to the one I was originally using, and nothing was wrong with either in terms of the computation side of things. Forgot to add I'm a physics student, and this project was meant to make me realise that **Cd** , the drag coefficient, decreases with speed. After changing this value, I'm getting the results I need.